# PHP loop with increased numeric value added to text

Tags: php, loops

I've been trying to find a quicker way to add the following code ...

```
    if (empty($insert1 = insert($language_id, 'step_one', 1))) {
        $insert1 = insert(1, 'step_one', 1);
    }

    if (empty($insert2 = insert($language_id, 'step_one', 2))) {
        $insert2 = insert(1, 'step_one', 2);
    }

    if (empty($insert3 = insert($language_id, 'step_one', 3))) {
        $insert3 = insert(1, 'step_one', 3);
    }

// continues up to $insert35
```

I can build an array of values showing ...

```
$array = array('$insert1', '$insert2', '$insert3'); // up to $insert35
```

But when I loop through the array, it doesn't work ...

```
$count = 1;
foreach($array as $value) {

    if (empty($value = insert($language_id, 'step_one', $count))) {
        $value = insert(1, 'step_one', $count);
    }
$count++;
}
```

In the body of the page, I am calling the snippets as ...

```
echo $insert1;

echo $insert2;

echo $insert3;
```

But the error shows as ...

Undefined variable: insert1

Undefined variable: insert2

Undefined variable: insert3

etc

Currently I am writing each step manually but there must be a better way to do it using a loop.

Comment: What on earth is `insert()`???

Comment: This is what arrays for.

Comment: Are you running this insert generation code in a function?

Comment: Looks like a `for ($x=1; $x<$max; $x++) {}` would do it quite nicely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample with arrays:

```
$count = 35;
$insert_results = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $count ; $i++) {
    $res = insert($language_id, 'step_one', $i + 1);
    if ($res) {
        // if `insert` runs successfully
        $insert_results[$i] = insert(1, 'step_one', $i + 1);
    } else {
        // if `insert` fails, you can even 
        // omit `else`-part if you want
        $insert_results[$i] = false;    // or NULL or -1
    }
}
```